# Write Salesforce App in PHP and publish it to market place

Tags: php, salesforce

If it possible to write Salesforce app in PHP and publish it to their marketplace or i must use APEX?

Thankx

Comment: I cant say for certain whether you can publish to their marketplace but you can definitely write applications in PHP that use the Force.com API using SOAP

Answer (score 2):

Anything that's published on the AppExchange that is intended to *run on* Force.com must be written in Apex (and probably Visualforce for the markup).

However, you can publish apps that are composite apps with, in your case, a PHP app executing outside Force.com that uses web services or other means to communicate with the Force.com platform.

But if you think of Force.com like Heroku or Azure or another PaaS, it's similar but Apex is the only supported language. You can also build applications through configurations without writing any code.

Comment: Hi Adam, Is it possible for me to list my J2ee web application on AppExchange. I use MySql should I migrate my Database server for this requirement.

I have my question posted in this link.

[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373589/can-we-list-a-j2ee-web-application-in-appexchange)